# How to create a 'NaT' in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to create a "NaT" (the analog of `float('NaN')` but with time) in Python. Can this be done natively in Python or using the `datetime` library? How?

I know that `numpy` and `pandas` can do this (or something similar), but I feel that if I need to import a library for this it should be `datetime`, not `numpy` or `pandas`.

Comment: good question.  I see how to do this in pandas and numpy, but not datetime

Comment: `NaT` is something specific to the numpy datetime dtype, as far as I know

Comment: This is a clear x-y problem. Of course you don't need NaT, if you are not using numpy, but you haven't explained why you think you need it, so it is impossible to say how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it does not look like `datetime` supports this notation. Looking at the code for how `NaT` is implemented in `pandas`, it looks like they create a class of type `datetime`, and insert the desired `NaT` behavior by overriding the operations. This leads me to believe it does not exist in datetime or they would use that. See [pandas _NaT class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/20d096408afbdf0ca18638b88fb34026b5498ba7/pandas/_libs/tslibs/nattype.pyx#L107)

Also this is further evidenced by this output testing conversion of pandas timestamps to datetimes.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Timestamp('10/2020').to_pydatetime()
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 0, 0)

pd.Timestamp('NaT').to_pydatetime()
Out[3]: NaT

type(pd.Timestamp('NaT').to_pydatetime())
Out[4]: pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType
```

Note that the `NaT` does not produce a `datetime.datetime` type.

In conclusion your options are:

1. Implement your own `NaT` class of type datetime similar to pandas (may be difficult).
2. *Use numpy*. In `numpy` the `NaT` can be found with `np.datetime64('nat')`. Numpy documentation about working with missing time. [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.datetime.html)
3. *Use pandas*. In pandas the `NaT` can be found with `pd.NaT` or interpreted through timestamp `pd.Timestamp('nat')`. The Pandas documentation there is a full section about working with missing data and how it is handled with Datetimes
   [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#datetimes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using errors='coerce' and inputting an invalid date (eg y=222)